# Reason for CSS property precedence?

Tags: css, standards

I actually know how the browsers tend to render the following examples (results based on Opera 9.5 and Firefox 3.0), but I don't understand the reason behind them.

Take this example,

```
<style type="text/css">
#outer{color:red;}
.inner{color:blue;}
</style>

<div id="outer" class="outer">
    <div id="inner" class="inner">
        <span>testing</span>
    </div> 
</div>
```

The result is blue text.

However, now see this example,

```
<style type="text/css">
#outer span{color:red;}
.inner span{color:blue;}
</style>

<div id="outer" class="outer">
    <div id="inner" class="inner">
        <span>testing</span>
    </div> 
</div>
```

The text is now red.

Finally, try this,

```
<style type="text/css">
#outer span{color:red;}
#inner span{color:blue;}
</style>

<div id="outer" class="outer">
    <div id="inner" class="inner">
        <span>testing</span>
    </div> 
</div>
```

Once again we have blue text.

Is there a specific reason for this methodology?

(sorry about the unclear title, it's the best I could manage.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**In example 1** the span element is not directly targeted, so we must look into how [CSS Inheritance](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#inheritance) is handled.  Color is an inherited property so we need to look at the span's closest parent element to determine color.  In your example 1 case, the class (.inner) has color blue defined and passes that inheritance down to the span.

**In example 2** the span element is directly targeted by both rules, so we must look into the [CSS Cascade](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#cascade) to determine which of the rules that targets the element is most specific. The rule with the ID selector wins.

**In example 3** we invoke the CSS Cascade rules once again and since both specificities are equal, last rule wins.

Note that in this situation:

```
 #outer {color: red; }
 span {color: blue; }
```

The text will be blue.  This is because the second rule targets the element directly and therefore does not invoke the CSS Cascade.

More Reading:

- [CSS Specificity Wars](http://www.stuffandnonsense.co.uk/archives/css_specificity_wars.html)
- [Understanding Specificity](http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/understanding_c/)
- [CSS for Poker Players](http://iamacamera.org/default.aspx?id=95)

Note and Disclosure: I authored the third blog post.

Answer (score 2):

The W3C has a [detailed explanation](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#cascade) of exactly how CSS is supposed to cascade and take precedence.  For your exact situation, this is what is occurring:

1. While "color" is an inherited property, the inner selector targets the span itself, so it takes precedence.
2. Since they both now target the span, the one that is more specific (the id selector) now takes precedence.
3. They are now both equally specific, and thus the declaration that appears later takes precedence.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this explanation helps:

EX 1) Because these are general rules, it applies the color of the immediate parent .inner

EX 2) An ID is more specific than a class (since there is only one element with a given ID) therefore the id selector is considered more specific and important

EX 3) Because the 2 rules are equally specific it chooses the last rule

Darko

Comment: The explanation of the third example is not correct. The styles apply to the span, not the parents.

Answer (score 0):

The cascade (the the 'C' in CSS) is well defined to allow a clear definition of what rules will take precedence (including allowing for important, user and agent rules).

But the rules are also not simple (thing of complex matches with large hierarchies specified).

The last step of the cascade is document order of the declaration, with last winning.

Comment: I think you mean the 'C' in CSS.

Answer (score 0):

In the first example the first style applies to the outer div. The inner div then inherits this style, but the second style applies to the inner div so it overrides the inherited style.

In the second example both styles apply to the span. The first style takes precedence because an id is more specific than a class.

In the third example both styles also apply to the span. As they have the same specificity, the last style takes precedence just because it's last.

You can read more about how precedence is determined [here](http://css.maxdesign.com.au/selectutorial/advanced_conflict.htm).